# How to install glxinfo32 on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, opengl

I'd like to install the `glxinfo32` app on Fedora. I'm using Fedora 22. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may mean `glxinfo32`. It's in the package glx-utils.i686, see https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/glx-utils/overview/

To install type (I don't know)